# How to increase the time limit for onLongPress?

Tags: flutter

I am fairly new to flutter. I know that the long press is fired when the user touches the screen for more than 500 milliseconds. Is there a way to change it to maybe like 2 seconds?

In my code I used inkresponse to get two different functions from the fab. On tap it goes to 1st page and on long press it goes to the 2nd page. I wanted the long press to be fairly longer and maybe add animation to indicate that the button is being pressed.

Here is the code that I have written-

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: 
  FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: InkResponse(
        splashColor: Colors.tealAccent,
             onLongPress: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => new firstPage(),));
          },
        child: new Container(
          width: 57.0,
          height: 57.0,

          child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(1, 1.05),
           child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => new secondpage(),
              ));},
        ),),
      ),),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onPanDown` and `onPanCancel` of `GestureDetector` to achieve that behavior. For simplicity, I removed `InkResponse`. You're free to wrap the `GestureDetector` in `InkWell`.

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
        onPanCancel: () => _timer?.cancel(),
        onPanDown: (_) => {
          _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            // Your function goes here
          })
        },
        child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `GestureDetector`s `onPan` has some downsides, like still considering it a long press when the pointer has moved too much between touch down and the timer going off. In addition, the timer has to be canceled; not only when the pan is canceled but also when it is complete, when the widget is removed from the tree (maybe that last one is handled by onCancel too?).

Answer (score 4):

Using `RawGestureDetector` you have more customisation options:

```dart
RawGestureDetector(
  gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
    LongPressGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
      () => LongPressGestureRecognizer(
        debugOwner: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ),
      (LongPressGestureRecognizer instance) {
        instance.onLongPress = () => print("Pressed long");
      },
    ),
  },
  child: Container(
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    color: Color(0xffff0000),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but the pointer problem remained the same in this method as well.

Comment: If i move the pointer away from the button while pressing the screen then too it will record it as a 2 sec press if i hold the press for that time.

Comment: The best answer, this solution also works with several nested gesture detectors

Comment: Regarding moving the pointer away, the constructor also has a postAcceptSlopTolerance that let’s you limit how far away the pointer may travel before the gesture is cancelled.

Comment: You need `import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';` for this solution! Plz include that in your answer, thank you! 